# How to get around mutable and immutable references?

Tags: rust

I'm creating a library that tries to be a Cache struct that wraps some structure that would be the component that retrieves "fresh data" for example through some HTTP requests; and also a backend field that is the actual cache backend for the data retrieved through the wrapped component.

I'm facing some problems when trying to "refresh" the data in the cache after retrieving some new data.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub trait Cacheable<K, V>
    where K: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash
{
    fn get(&self, k: &K) -> Option<&V>;
    fn set(&mut self, k: K, v: V);
    fn del(&mut self, k: &K);
}

pub struct Cache<'a, K, V>
    where K: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash
{
    wrapped: &'a dyn Cacheable<K, V>,
    backend: Box<dyn Cacheable<K, V>>,
}

impl<'a, K, V> Cache<'a, K, V>
    where K: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash + 'static,
          V: 'static,
{
    fn New(wrapped: &'a dyn Cacheable<K, V>, backend_type: BackendType) -> Self {
        let backend = match backend_type {
            BackendType::Memory => MemoryBackend::<K, V>::New(),
        };

        Cache {
            wrapped: wrapped,
            backend: Box::new(backend),
        }
    }

    fn get(&mut self, k: &K) -> Option<&V> {
        // PROBLEM 1:
        // Borrow backend here as immutable
        if let Some(v) = self.backend.get(k) {
            return Some(v)
        }
        
        if let Some(v) = self.wrapped.get(k) {
            let cache_k = *k.clone(); // PROBLEM 2: How to clone reference value?
            let cache_v = *v.clone(); // PROBLEM 2: How to clone reference value?

            // PROBLEM 1:
            // Borrow backend here as mutable
            self.backend.set(cache_k, cache_v);
            return Some(v)
        }

        None
    }
}

pub enum BackendType {
    Memory
} 

pub struct MemoryBackend<K, V>
    where K: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash
{
    data: HashMap<K, V>,
}

impl<K, V> Cacheable<K, V> for MemoryBackend<K, V>
    where K: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash
{
    fn get(&self, k: &K) -> Option<&V> {
        self.data.get(k)
    }

    fn set(&mut self, k: K, v: V) {
        self.data.insert(k, v);
    }

    fn del(&mut self, k: &K) {
        self.data.remove(k);
    }
}

impl<K, V> MemoryBackend<K, V>
    where K: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash
{
    fn New() -> Self {
        MemoryBackend {
            data: HashMap::<K, V>::new(),
        }
    }
}
```

###### Problem 1

Possible coexistence of mutable and immutable references. What would be the best option here?

I tried changing the `get` method signature to return an `Option<V>` instead of `Option<&V>` but that leads me also to the problem 2, for which I can't seem to be able to clone the value of a shared reference.

###### Problem 2

```
move occurs because value has type `K`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
help: consider borrowing here: `&*k.clone()`"
```

AFAIK I don't want to set `Copy` trait as bound of `V` because it might not be a simple type and would much rather clone its value than setting that as an API restriction. I can't seem to work around this.

Comment: [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) should help you to make `get` accept `&self`, while still being able to change `backend`

Comment: Problem 2 can be easily solved if you first `self.backend.set`, then `return self.backend.get(cache_k);`, unless performance is too critical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > **Problem 1**: Possible coexistence of mutable and immutable references. What would be the best option here? I tried changing the `get` method signature to return an `Option<V>` instead of `Option<&V>` but that leads me also to the problem 2, for which I can't seem to be able to clone the value of a shared reference.

   You could add a `get_or_insert` method to the trait, and implement it for `MemoryBackend` using the `hash_map::Entry` API:

   ```rust
   fn get_or_insert(&mut self, k: K, v: Option<V>) -> Option<&V> {
       match self.data.entry(k) {
           Entry::Occupied(entry) => Some(entry.into_mut()),
           Entry::Vacant(entry) => v.map(|v| &*entry.insert(v)),
       }
   }
   ```

   Or, to avoid evaluating `v` unless it's actually required (which an optimisation pass might already do if the above is inlined), you could instead pass in a function that returns `Option<V>`:

   ```rust
   fn get_or_insert_with(&mut self, k: K, f: &dyn Fn() -> Option<V>) -> Option<&V> {
       match self.data.entry(k) {
           Entry::Occupied(entry) => Some(entry.into_mut()),
           Entry::Vacant(entry) => f().map(|v| &*entry.insert(v)),
       }
   }
   ```

   Note that, in order for `Cacheable` to be object-safe, we have to use the indirection of a function-trait object here (which, again, an optimisation pass might eliminate if the above is inlined).
2. > **Problem 2**:
   > *"move occurs because value has type `K`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   > help: consider borrowing here: `&*k.clone()`"*
   > AFAIK I don't want to set `Copy` trait as bound of `V` because it might not be a simple type and would much rather clone its value than setting that as an API restriction.
   > So I can't seem to work around this.

   You could add `K: Clone` and `V: Clone` constraints to the implementation:

   ```rust
   impl<'a, K, V> Cache<'a, K, V>
   where
       K: Clone + std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash + 'static,
       V: Clone + 'static,
   {
       // etc
   }
   ```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=5023c93efb1da5216c3058afd8aae926))